# Keeping my web app running after Browser close

Tags: asp.net, browser, keep-alive

I have a aspx web application that updates or adds files in a database. The clients access through the browser and one of the requirements is that they can start the update and be able to close the browser while the update continues.  It appears to run for a little bit after I close the browser but then it stops. How can you keep the application running for asp.net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's something you could very well solve with [WF (Workflow Foundation)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663328.aspx). Create a workflow for the task that should survive closing the browser. Workflows have their own threads and livecycles separate from ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

The web application will keep running in the application pool, but this will be recycled eventually. As long as the users session runs the application should be kept alive, so by upping the session timeout you may fix the problem.

A better approach though would be to move the long-running task into a service instead, but that may require a rewrite of your application.

Answer (score 1):

Usually for long-running or asynchronous processing, you want to dispatch the request to a back-end service to handle.  Trying to keep the web-app alive to finish processing can lead to problems, especially with HTTP and session timeouts.

A common pattern for this is to put the request on a message queue and let a back-end service process it when it can.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a separate windows service that you can push jobs onto from your web application, then check the status of the job(s) when the user logs in again.

The windows service won't be tied to the asp.net app domain so it will continue to run regardless of whats happening in your web application.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this pattern and you have to decouple the work from the  HTTP request. The way we've solved it is to abstract the computing to be done as an event to be scheduled. So, say a user at a browser takes an action that requires a long lived (relatively) computation on the back end, this computation is given a name like 'doXYZForUser' and given a prameter vector like (userId, params...) and sent off to the work queue. Some time in the future the user logs in again and can see what the status of their job is.

I'm running a Java stack and a Java Message Service (JMS) but the principle is the same. The request from the browser queues up an event and the browser get an ACK back saying the event is on the work queue. The queue is managed by an entirely separately running process which in .NET I believe is just called the Message Queue. The job comes up on the queue gets processed and the results can be placed in a separate table containing a reference to the user that kicked off the job, so the next time they log in job status/results can be returned.